# Connection error SASL error with QPID and AmqNetLite

Tags: c#, amqp, qpid, sasl

I am not familiar with AMQP. 
I try to connect a AmqpNetLite program to a Qpid server and I get the following exception : 
Amqp.AmqpException: sasl-mechanisms(sasl-server-mechanisms:[CRAM-MD5,SCRAM-SHA-1,SCRAM-SHA-256])

Note : I am able to connect to a basic AMQP server, but not QPID.

Here is the code to create the connection:

Please tell where to start to fix my problem.

```
void Main(string[] args)
{     
    try
    {
    Address address = new Address("amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672");
    Connection connection = new Connection(address);
    Session session = new Session(connection);
    ReceiverLink receiver = new ReceiverLink(session, "receiver-link", "queue");
    Message message = receiver.Receive();
    receiver.Accept(message);
    receiver.Close();
    session.Close();
    connection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Could you confirm which Qpid server implementation you are using (and version)?  The Apache Qpid project has two: Qpid CPP Broker and Qpid Broker-J (which is a Java implementation).

Comment: Qpid Broker-J version : 6.1
AmqpNetLite 2.1.6

Answer (score 1):

The error would seem to indicate that the broker is not able to provide the client with a SASL mechanism that it supports.  I think that AmqpNetLite only does ANONYMOUS, PLAIN and EXTERNAL but perhaps that's changed.  You could look into your broker configuration and make one of those mechanisms available to the client and that will probably allow for a match and successful authentication.  Or you could use an SSL connection which would then allow those SASL mechanisms to work and provide a bit of extra security for you connection.

The [security section](https://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-cpp-1.39.0/cpp-broker/book/chap-Messaging_User_Guide-Security.html) of the Broker-J documentation site should shed some light on this for you.

Comment: Yes, that's true :
only SASL PLAIN, EXTERNAL, and ANONYMOUS are currently supported.